# How to take data from mysql and echo links on a page?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a website where you can post a question and it creates a page for that question in mysql database. We have it currently so the link to that persons question is based off their name they enter in at the homepage. But I want to be able to display all of the questions in the databases as links on a page? I appreciate any help I'm still learning PHP. By the way, I am using php to build this.
Sorry if this is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $result = //some result value from query

 while($page = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<a href='".$page['link']."'>".$page['linkvalue']."</a>";
 } //echo out the link in a tag and also value
```